# VS C++ - Unresolved external symbol

Tags: c++, visual-studio

I am trying to use the cryptopp565 c++ library and has a given string with RIPEMD160 hashing.  Unable to build a program in VS.  Please see the attached image.  Appreciate your inputs!

https://i.stack.imgur.com/8iW2o.jpg

---

```
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error   LNK2019 unresolved external symbol "public: __thiscall CryptoPP::Algorithm::Algorithm(bool)" (??0Algorithm@CryptoPP@@QAE@_N@Z) referenced in function "public: __thiscall CryptoPP::BufferedTransformation::BufferedTransformation(void)" (??0BufferedTransformation@CryptoPP@@QAE@XZ)  CrytpoTest  D:\Pers\temp\VS\CrytpoTest\CrytpoTest\CryptoTestclass.obj   1   
Error   LNK2001 unresolved external symbol "public: virtual bool __thiscall CryptoPP::HashTransformation::TruncatedVerify(unsigned char const *,unsigned int)" (?TruncatedVerify@HashTransformation@CryptoPP@@UAE_NPBEI@Z)  CrytpoTest  D:\Pers\temp\VS\CrytpoTest\CrytpoTest\CryptoTestclass.obj   1   
Error   LNK2001 unresolved external symbol "public: virtual unsigned int __thiscall CryptoPP::BufferedTransformation::GetMaxWaitObjectCount(void)const " (?GetMaxWaitObjectCount@BufferedTransformation@CryptoPP@@UBEIXZ)   CrytpoTest  D:\Pers\temp\VS\CrytpoTest\CrytpoTest\CryptoTestclass.obj   1   
Error   LNK2001 unresolved external symbol "public: virtual void __thiscall CryptoPP::BufferedTransformation::GetWaitObjects(class CryptoPP::WaitObjectContainer &,class CryptoPP::CallStack const &)" (?GetWaitObjects@BufferedTransformation@CryptoPP@@UAEXAAVWaitObjectContainer@2@ABVCallStack@2@@Z)    CrytpoTest  D:\Pers\temp\VS\CrytpoTest\CrytpoTest\CryptoTestclass.obj   1   
Error   LNK2001 unresolved external symbol "public: virtual void __thiscall CryptoPP::BufferedTransformation::Initialize(class CryptoPP::NameValuePairs const &,int)" (?Initialize@BufferedTransformation@CryptoPP@@UAEXABVNameValuePairs@2@H@Z)    CrytpoTest  D:\Pers\temp\VS\CrytpoTest\CrytpoTest\CryptoTestclass.obj   1   
Error   LNK2001 unresolved external symbol "public: virtual bool __thiscall CryptoPP::BufferedTransformation::Flush(bool,int,bool)" (?Flush@BufferedTransformation@CryptoPP@@UAE_N_NH0@Z)   CrytpoTest  D:\Pers\temp\VS\CrytpoTest\CrytpoTest\CryptoTestclass.obj   1   
Error   LNK2001 unresolved external symbol "public: virtual bool __thiscall CryptoPP::BufferedTransformation::MessageSeriesEnd(int,bool)" (?MessageSeriesEnd@BufferedTransformation@CryptoPP@@UAE_NH_N@Z)   CrytpoTest  D:\Pers\temp\VS\CrytpoTest\CrytpoTest\CryptoTestclass.obj   1
```

Comment: Don't attach images of text. You attached the error log (and I formatted it for you). Attach that short code **as text** in the post itself.

Comment: [Also, read this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12573816/what-is-an-undefined-reference-unresolved-external-symbol-error-and-how-do-i-fix). You should have googled and come across this post before posting your own.

Comment: It's obvious, you have not linked to Crypto++ library